# Orthogonal space to a subspace of L2

Tags: integration, orthogonal-polynomials

Consider $L^2([-1,1])$ and
$$ V= \{f(x) = ax + bx^2 : x \in [-1,1], a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
Find $V^\perp \subset L^2([-1,1])$.

I'm having issues answering this question. Is there a way to find $f(x)$ in a "explicit way" such that it belongs to $V^\perp$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The [Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) polynomials
$$P_n(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{n!2^n\sqrt{2}}D^n((1-x^2)^n),$$
where $D$ is the derivative operator, form a complete orthonormal system for $L_2([-1,1])$. The first three Legendre polynomials are $P_0(x)=1$, $P_1(x)=x$ and $P_2(x)=\frac12(3x^2-1)$. Then $\operatorname{span}\{P_1,P_2+\frac12P_0\}=V$, where $V$ is as in your problem. Then, the span of $\{P_n:n>2\}\cup\{P_2-P_0\}$ is $V^\perp$, since
$$(P_2+\frac12P_0,P_2-P_0)=(P_2,P_2)+\frac12(P_0,P_2)-(P_2,P_0)-(P_0,P_0)=1-1=0$$

The Legendre polynomials may be obtained by considering the collection of polynomials $\{x^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}$ ($\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$), whose span is dense in $L_2([-1,1])$ (by the Stone-Weirstrass theorem), and apply the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization procedure.

Another way to analyze your problem, is to  order the polynomials $\{x^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ as $\{x, x^2,1,x^3,\ldots\}$ and apply the Gram-Schmidt process. $V=\operatorname{span}\{x,x^2\}$.